# How to join substrate as infrastructure provider

Tags: substrate-node-template, parachain, nodes, rpc-server

I wanted to know the complete process of joining polkadot builders as infrastructure provider but could not get a proper guide explaining that. Can someone please tell the process and what happens in each step of the process.
I have read the substrate web page of SBP but it does not tell the process in detail and just gives a overview of it.
Requesting other teams that have successfully joined or graduated substrate builders program to help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's great you are interested in the Substrate Builders program. How the program works is that you submit your interest and expect to be connected with a member of the program team to understand more about your project and the level of development completed so far. Traditionally, the program focuses on strong teams that are far along the journey with a prototype and is looking to productionize their prototype.

That being said, the programs are reconfiguring as we speak, we are rapidly changing the programs available to make it more community-led and self-service. So best to stay tuned to the updates.